# printing character in a square of board without arrays C program

Tags: arrays, c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int size;
    int i ;
    int k;

    printf("room size : ");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    for(k=2; k<=size; k++) {
        for(i=0; i<=size; i++) {
            printf("| ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for(i=0; i<=size; i++) {
        printf("| ");
    }
}
```

and output is:

```
room size : 5
| | | | | | 
| | | | | | 
| | | | | | 
| | | | | | 
| | | | | |
```

I want to print a character With char 'C' in a random square of this board but I cant use arrays. How to store this rooms without arrays?

expected output is( example: random coordinates are 3,4)

```
room size : 5
| | | | | | 
| | | | | | 
| | | | | | 
| | |C| | | 
| | | | | |
```

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a random number?

Comment: no. I want to print a 'C' on random coordinate. but dont know how to point the coordinates

Comment: I mean, I have (3,4) coordinats and I want to print 'C' on (3,4)  but cant do without arrays cuz I dont know how to point (3,4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all grid squares to have a `' '` (space) as its content, except for one specific square which should have `'C'` as its content, then one way of printing the grid is to check in every loop iteration whether you are printing this specific square or not. If you are, then you print `'C'`, otherwise you print `' '`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main( void )
{
    int size;
    int random_x, random_y;

    //seed random number generator
    srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );

    //get the size of the room from the user
    printf( "Room size: " );
    scanf( "%d", &size );

    //generate a random set of coordinates for the
    //grid square which should have the 'C'
    random_x = rand() % size;
    random_y = rand() % size;

    //print the grid
    for ( int y = 0; y < size; y++ )
    {
        for( int x = 0; x < size; x++ )
        {
            printf( "|" );

            if ( x == random_x && y == random_y )
            {
                printf( "C" );
            }
            else
            {
                printf( " " );
            }
        }

        printf( "|\n" );
    }
}
```

Here is an example output of the program (the selected grid square is random):

```
Room size: 5
| | | | | |
| |C| | | |
| | | | | |
| | | | | |
| | | | | |
```